# how to show an ideal is maximal ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $k$ be field and consider the polynamial ring $R=k[x]$. Let $x_0\in k$ and consider the principal ideal $m=(x-x_0)$ of $R$. Show $m$ is maximal ideal

I think to show $m=R-U(R)$ but it doesnt work (or I can't)

$U(R)$ means unit of $R$

any suggestion?

Comment: Do u know that R/m is a field iff m is maximal?

Comment: @JackYoon Yes.. But I try to construct homomorphism from $R$ to a field(?) whose kernel is $(x-x_0)$ but I couldn't

Comment: Do you know that $k[x]$ is Euclidean so a PID, so an ideal $(1) \supsetneq (f) \supsetneq (x-a)$ would yield a *proper* factor $\,f\,$ of $\,x-a,\,$ contradiction.

Comment: I dont understand @BillDubuque

Comment: Understand *what*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you worked it out by now but if not there you go.

But before we start let's note $m \neq R-U(R)$. This is only true if $R$ is a local ring, (which means it has a unique maximum ideal) and if $x_0\neq 0$ then $m$ clearly does not contain $x$ but $x$ is most definitely not a unit.

$R/m= k[x]/(x-x_0) \cong k$ (consider the map $f \mapsto f(x_0)$ ) and therefore $m$ is a maximal ideal.